# SPList Object is null After back/restore SITE

Tags: list, backup, restore, secure-store

after a bakup/ restore of SPWEB, if  I try to Get a SPLIST by Server object Model code, it returns me

```
 public bool OnNotification(SPAlertHandlerParams ahp)
 {
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ahp.siteUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SPList lookupList = web.Lists[new Guid(ahp.a.ListID.ToString())];
                        //list = web.Lists[ahp.a.ListID];
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image]

> List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

If I try to get the same list using COM, the result is success:

```
 string siteUrl = "http://mysite/";
            SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("mylist");

            clientContext.Load(oList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using below?

```
var list = web.TryGetList("Title");
```

I think the problem with your SSOM code is quite obvious. Let me know if snippet above works.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I added the full snippet above. The object is an Alert. And it's got some List information about the List the alert come from but not the ListName. The problems is that, how you can see above, When I try to get the the list from the site, the code can't find it.